# VideoJS doesn't play in Firefox even with .htaccess modified as suggested

Tags: video, html5-video

I'm having a great challenge to enable VideoJS "Video for Everybody" play in Firefox 3.6.

I read so many posts and I've followed so many suggestions, but still videos can't play in firefox. However, videos play in Chrome, IE etc. This is my code:

HTML:

```
 <video class="video-js" width="440" height="264" controls preload>
          <source src="http://www.mcintyrebills.com/HGTV_top_10.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          <source src="http://www.mcintyrebills.com/HGTV_top_10.webm"  type="video/webm" />
          <source src="http://www.mcintyrebills.com/HGTV_top_10.ogg" type="video/ogg"  />
          <!-- Flash Fallback. Use any flash video player here. Make sure to keep the vjs-flash-fallback class. -->
          <object id="flash_fallback_1" class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="440" height="264" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
            data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
            <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
            <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />

                        <param name="flashvars" 
              value='config={"playlist":["http://www.mcintyrebills.com/logo.png", {"url": "http://www.mcintyrebills.com/HGTV_top_10.mp4","autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true}]}' />
            <!-- Image Fallback. Typically the same as the poster image. -->
            <img src="http://www.mcintyrebills.com/logo.png" width="440" height="264" alt="Poster Image" 
              title="No video playback capabilities." />
          </object>
    </video>
```

On the Apache server I have in .htaccess file:

```
  AddType video/mp4 .mp4
  AddType video/ogg .ogv
  AddType video/webm .webm
  AddType video/x-m4v .m4v
  AddType application/ogg .ogg 

  // Comment - This is to prevent compression of video files, as suggested.
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(og[gv]|mp4|m4v|webm)$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

I thought I did everything that is asking for and still can't play in Firefox 3.6. Please help?

Here is the beta page I'm trying to display video in firefox.

```
  http://www.mcintyrebills.com/video.html
```

The video you'll find under:

```
 Press --> HGTV's Top 10 (last link)
```

Thanks,

Comment: I think I found the solution. After I changed: "AddType video/ogg .ogv" to "AddType video/ogg .ogg" now video in Firefox 3.6 works just fine. I'm a happy man again!

I hope that helps you guys so you don't waste so much time like me! 

Cheers,
partizan

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried swapping the video sources? I used this and works fine,

```
    <source src="http://www.mcintyrebills.com/HGTV_top_10.ogv" type='video/ogg'>
    <source src="http://www.mcintyrebills.com/HGTV_top_10.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <source src="http://www.mcintyrebills.com/HGTV_top_10.webm" type='video/webm'>
```

This means that latest version that I'm using (FF 11)  was ignoring mp4 and webm sources.